# Non-surjective isometries of $l_p$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces

It is well known that all surjective isometries of $l_p$ for $p\neq 2$ are the signed permutations of the unit vector basis $(e_n)$. Is there a characterization for the linear non-surjective isometries of $l_p$ for $p\neq 2$? If $(x_n)$ is a normalized block basis of $e_n$ then $e_n\to \varepsilon_n x_{\pi(n)}$ (where $\pi$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$) defines an isometry. But probably not all isometries are of this form.

Comment: The second time you're writing "permutation" (which means bijective self-map), you probably mean "injective self-map".

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference in this case. The injective self-map is a permutation on the range, and a subsequence of a block basis is also a block basis.

Comment: No, the injective self-map $n\mapsto n+1$ of $\mathbf{N}_{\ge 0}$ is not a permutation on its range $\mathbf{N}_{\ge 1}$.

Comment: You are right about that. Stil, does it make a difference in the end? I am not sure. For your example, after relableing the range we still get a permutation. If I am considering all block basis, am I missing an isometry by saying permutation instead of injective self-map?

Comment: Do you assume linearity? (It is for free in the surjective case by the Banach-Mazur Thm, but it is not guaranteed for non surjective isometries)

Comment: Good point. Yes, I mean linear non-surjective isometries.

Comment: Concerning the obvious isometries I think you should use sequences of normalized and disjoint supported vectors instead of block sequences.

Comment: Indeed! If $(x_n)$ are disjointly supported (not necessarily finitely support even), then one also gets isometries.

Comment: This boils down to the two-dimensional question whether the images of two standard basis vectors must have disjoint supports. Looks like it must be true but the formal proof still escapes me (though I haven't thought of it too long yet :-) )

Comment: For $p>2$ it is trivial: just consider $\lim_{t\to 0+}\frac{\|x+ty\|^p+\|x-ty\|^p-2\|x\|^p}{t^p}$. It is finite if the supports are disjoint and infinite otherwise.

Comment: And for $p<2$ and two unit vectors, one can use the same limit and compare it to $2$ instead of infinity...

Comment: Look up the Banach-Lamperti Theorem.

Comment: The whole point of a permutation is that the domain and the range are the same. If you relabel the the range, you have to relabel the domain too. This is pointless anyway, since your formulation is immediate to fix (writing "injective self-map" instead of permutations, since permutation precisely correspond to surjective isometries.